# CORS not working anymore

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having a strange problem that from one day to another my AJAX requests for a website not working anymore.

I'm now struggling to get it working and can't find the problem.

this is my javascript:
basically it's realy simple, it retrieves the ip adres and then sends it (POST) to a site which stores it.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://dashboard.inofec.nl/ip', true);

    // If specified, responseType must be empty string or "text"
    xhr.responseType = 'text';

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    // console.log('R = ' + xhr.response);
                    // console.log('RT= ' + xhr.responseText);
                    tip = xhr.responseText;

                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('ip', tip);
                    formData.append('uri', turl);
                    formData.append('id', dataId);

                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open("POST", "https://dashboard.inofec.nl/visits");
                    request.send(formData);

                    // console.log('IP  = ' + tip);
                    // console.log('URL = ' + turl);
                    console.log('ID  = ' + dataId);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ERROR !');
                }
            }
        }
    xhr.send(null);
```

on the server I have now added this to avoid using a wildcard

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] != '') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
```

When I used only

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
>   I got the error:
>   Cross-Origin-request blocked: 
>   CORS-header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘*, *’).

And with the new headers i get

> CORS-header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://www.inofec.nl, *’).

But when I check the headers I see that it responds with the correct header.

> Access-control-allow-headers
>       Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With
>       access-control-allow-methods
>       GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
>       access-control-allow-origin http://www.inofec.nl, *

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' *'

Comment: When I go to the website I get "Failed to load https://dashboard.inofec.nl/ip: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://www.inofec.nl, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.inofec.nl' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: So, I have changed the header to header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); And it is still not working, although the respons is now access-control-allow-origin *, *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yvo Cilon made me think about the multiple values.
And pointed me in the right direction.

I searched for headers and noticed that on the webserver there was a header already set and I added it in my code.

I removed the header set in the webserver to have control on how and when it is used.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.