# Cant get vanilla JS onreadystatechange function / readyState 4 to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a "log in" page for a HotSpot. Once a user inputs his/her email, they gain internet access.

To make this work, I'm using two AJAX functions.

1. After clicking submit, username and password are sent to the router (which grants the user internet access)
2. The 2cnd AJAX call is made, which saves the email to the database (after the user gets internet access (it should be sent right after he gets internet access and before he gets redirected)).

Currently, I'm having trouble getting ...

`xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){`

... function to work.

Ajax calls are made to early, the user gets instantly redirected and emails are not saved in the database (I assume it's becouse they are sent before the user has internet access).

Any help you could give me will be much appriciated.

HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>HotSpot</title>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Email Form, which gets saved into the DB -->
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="mail" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="mail">
        <h1>Hotspot</h1>
        <h2>To gain internet access, enter your email.</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);
function SendAjax() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    console.log(email);
    // Check if fields are empty 
    if (email=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.");
    }
    // AJAX code to submit form
    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));

                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                    if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has also been tried, but it doesen't work.

```
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                  if (this.readyState === DONE){
                    etc etc
                  }
```

PHP document (I don't think it matters for this instance, but you know... just in case)

```
<?php

    require ('connect.php');

    $clean_email = "";
    $cleaner_email = "";


    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        //sanitize with filter
        $clean_email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //sanitize with test_input
        $cleaner_email = test_input($clean_email);
        //validate with filter
        if (filter_var($cleaner_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            // email is valid and ready for use
            echo "Email is valid";  
            //Email is a row inside the database
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO addresses (Email) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $cleaner_email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            // email is invalid and should be rejected
            echo "Invalid email, try again";
        } 
    } else {
    echo "Please enter an email";
    }

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

    $DB->close();   
?>
```

Edit:

Pasting a snippet of the code, which is changed.

```
        else{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://router.login', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");

            var xhr2= new XMLHttpRequest();

            var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(DONE);
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(DONE);              
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server.insertDB.php', true);
                    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));                  
                }
            }
            xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));  
        }
    }
```

I needed to move the email variable outside, otherwise I was getting an error that it isn't defined.

I'm getting an error on `xhr2.send` now...

*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED. at HTMLInputElement.SendAjax*

Comment: In event handlers, like `onreadystatechange`, `this` is probably not you, but the `xhr`. Check it with logging, and if that is the case, save "your" `this` into a variable in the closure (or you can add it to the `xhr` too if you really want to).

Comment: To be fair this sentance doesn't make much sense to me. I'm not really that experianced with `this` statements and their giving me trouble. How would I log this? console.log (DONE); I assume? Documentation for this function can be found here --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_onreadystatechange_event_listener

Comment: did the console.log(DONE); and it did get 4. I went through it with debugger and it took about 5 sec to send the 1st AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your listener BEFORE sending the request. Here an exapmle using the onload listener

```
    // Set up our HTTP request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Setup our listener to process completed requests
    xhr.onload = function () {

        // Process our return data
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            // What do when the request is successful
            console.log('success!', xhr);
        } else {
            // What do when the request fails
            console.log('The request failed!');
        }

        // Code that should run regardless of the request status
        console.log('This always runs...');
    };

    // Create and send a GET request
    // The first argument is the post type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
    // The second argument is the endpoint URL
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    xhr.send();
```

Here an example with the ready state change listener

```
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Here is your code with the right calling order

```
function SendAjax() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    console.log(email);
    // Check if fields are empty 
    if (email=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.");
    }
    // AJAX code to submit form
    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;

                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                    if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                    }
                };
                xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
            }
        }

        xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not requesting anything, so I don't know why I would need the onload function, especially if my xhr request is made outside the scope of the function...

Comment: Of course youre requesting a POST request

"The XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onload is the function called when an XMLHttpRequest transaction completes successfully."

Comment: the onload listener is not the point here, the point is you have to set the listener before sending the request. i ve addded another example

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll give it a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: Wait. Now I'm even more confused. How could xhr.readyState be done, when we haven't even set the xhr yet (as it is outside the brackets).

Comment: I mean, I would imagine that I need to make 1. Ajax call, which grants the user internet access. In the meantime I listen untill it gets the readyState to DONE, after which I make the 2cnd Ajax call, so the users email gets sent to the DB. I again listen to the readyState and when the email is sent, the user gets redirected...

Comment: I've found a similair thing to what you posted, but I don't know how this readyState relates to my problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883146/cors-not-working-anymore?rq=1

Comment: Ive modified your code and added it to the answer, try it

Comment: Still the same thing. it redirects me before I get internet access, and it's not saved into the database, as again it does not have internet access. the point is that ajax doesn't wait for the 1st "datapack" to be sent (the one that gives the user internet access - submiting username and password), but just continues on with submiting to email and redirecting. Thanks for the help though. Happy new year =)